# dotnet aspnet-codegenerator fails with message that more than one DbContext with the same name has been found. But my project has only one

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a Host class

```
namespace Trivia.Models
{
    public class Host
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int SettingId { get; set; }
        //public HostSetting Setting { get; set; }
    }
}
```

A context

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Trivia.Models
{
    public class TriviaDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public TriviaDbContext(DbContextOptions<TriviaDbContext> options) 
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Host> Host { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Following line added to ConfigureServices method for class Startup

```
services.AddDbContext<TriviaDbContext>(options =>
                                                   options.UseSqlite("Data Source=Trivia.db"));
```

Running the command below

> dotnet aspnet-codegenerator controller -name HostsController -m Host
>   -dc TriviaDbContext --relativeFolderPath Controllers --useDefaultLayout --referenceScriptLibraries

gives the following error

> Building project ... Finding the generator 'controller'... Running the
>   generator 'controller'... Attempting to compile the application in
>   memory. Attempting to figure out the EntityFramework metadata for the
>   model and DbContext: 'Host' :
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[0]
>         User profile is available. Using '/Users/path/.aspnet/DataProtection-Keys' as key repository;
>   keys will not be encrypted at rest. More than one DbContext named
>   'Trivia.Models.TriviaDbContext' was found. Specify which one to use by
>   providing its fully qualified name using its exact case. StackTrace:
>   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.FindContextType(String
>   name)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(String
>   contextType)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkModelProcessor.TryCreateContextUsingAppCode(Type
>   dbContextType, Type startupType)
>
> More than one DbContext named 'Trivia.Models.TriviaDbContext' was
>   found. Specify which one to use by providing its fully qualified name
>   using its exact case.    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.ActionInvoker.b__6_0()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[]
>   args)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.ActionInvoker.Execute(String[]
>   args)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.CodeGenCommand.Execute(String[]
>   args) RunTime 00:00:11.61

I do not have multiple database contexts.

My program.cs file

```
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BuildWebHost(args).Run();
        }

        public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                //.UseStartup<Startup>()
                   .UseStartup(typeof(Startup).Assembly.FullName)
                .Build();
    }
```

uncommenting //.UseStartup() makes the application work.

I would still like the application to use StartupDevelopment based on my environment plus have the dotnet aspen-codegenerator work.

Comment: In my Program.cs file I modified the BuildWebHost to say .UseStartup(typeof(Startup).Assembly.FullName). With this line I get the error as described. With the default line .UseStartup<Startup>() everything works as expected without any errors. I would like the application to pick up my development environment without me adding if else code.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using StartupDevelopment you use ConfigureDevelopmentServices and setup your environment there like

```
public void ConfigureDevelopmentServices(IServiceCollection services) 
        {
            services.AddMvc();

            services.AddDbContext<TriviaDbContext>(options =>
                                                   options.UseSqlite(Configuration.GetConnectionString("TriviaDb")));
        }
```

Benefits

1. No need to use Startup{Enviornmentname} classes
2. No need to modify program.cs
3. Works with dotnet aspnet-generator

This approach is much better than using if/else conditions in ConfigureServices method.

Answer (score 0):

specifying context like so did it for me.  in dotnetcore 3.0

```
dotnet ef migrations add IntialCreate  --project .\Persistence\ -s .\API\  --context DataContext
```